# I'm making several requests for JSONP data using jQuery, how do I figure out which request goes with which result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

The results comeback out of order from the sequence I made them.  If I wait for each request to finish the results are OK but it takes longer than I'd like.  Is there a way for me to keep track of which result belongs to which request?

EDIT: Per request I'm adding the code that performs the JSON calls.

```
for (var i = 0; i < rssLinkDB.length; i++) {
  jQuery.getJSON(encoded, function(data){
    yLinkDB.push(data.query.results.result);
    index++;
    if (index == 10) {
      state = "RequestLikes";
    }
  });         
}
```

Comment: Could you show how you're making the requests? Kinda hard to imagine how they get "mixed–up" to begin with…

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling a server side method, you can use a custom HTTP Header as a flag to track the request/response ownership.

Add a **custom HTTP Header** in the server side method and use its key to get the value from the client side:

```
// In Server Side method (e.g ASP.NET Page Method):
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("MyCustomKey", "TheValue");


// In jQuery callback body:
var myCustomHeader = XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader("MyCustomKey");
// now do whatever you want based on myCustomHeader value...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the callback function names unique/dynamic, it's best to namespace these functions so that you don't pollute your global scope.

```
callbackHandlersNS.callback1 = function () {/* handle first request*/};
callbackHandlersNS.callback2 = function () {/* handle second request*/};
...
```

Comment: Would this still work if the number of requests I make is configurable?

Comment: If I allow the user to decide the number of requests to make and they choose 10.  Can I create 10 callback names at runtime?  If so is there a term I can lookup in Google or do you have a code snippet?

Comment: you simply need a `var counter = 0` then dynamically create a callback `callbackHandlersNS["callback"+counter++] = function() {/*handle request*/}`